# JSoup Parsing HTML Questions

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to use JSoup to parse some html that looks, roughly, like it does below:

```
<div class="mod qmy_text withanno">
    <ul class="yfncnhl mytext"></ul>
    <h3>
        <span>Monday, August 12, 1999</span>
    </h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="some_link_here">Title of My Article</a><cite>News
                Source<span>(&nbsp;(Sun, Aug 12)</span>
        </cite></li>
    </ul>
```

My question is, how can I parse that HTML so I can return only what is in `<cite>` -- Sun, Aug 12.

As of right now I am only able to output the date after h3 by using the expression

```
Elements links = doc.select("div[class=mod qmy_text withanno] > h3");
    System.out.println(links.text());
```

Comment: If you select the `span`, you get only 2 references, then you can go to the 2nd and select the date

Comment: Why are you selecting `h3` if date you are looking for is in `ul > li > a > cite > span`?

Comment: If you could help me with some code that would help more. I'm very new to JSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets format your HTML to include only path to element you want to find. It will look like

```
<div class="mod qmy_text withanno">
    ...
    <ul>
        <li>
            ...
            <cite>News Source
                 <span>(&nbsp;(Sun, Aug 12)</span>
            </cite>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

So your select can look like `div.mod.qmy_text.withanno > ul > li > cite > span`. So with code like

```
Elements span = doc.select("div.mod.qmy_text.withanno > ul > li > cite > span");
String spanText = span.text();
```

Our `spanText` will contain `( (Sun, Aug 12)`.

If you want to get only part between last `(` and last `)` to get `Sun, Aug 12` you can use

```
String date = spanText.substring(spanText.lastIndexOf('(')+1, spanText.lastIndexOf(')'));
```

Comment: You are an absolute GENIUS.. thank you so so so much!